# How to get woocommerce stock quantity from another woocommerce shop

Tags: woocommerce, synchronization, stock

I have two woocommerce shops, 
one of them have a lot of products and one of them is new.
both shop products are the same and the new one have some different products too.

now I want my new shop, get stock quantity and prices from the old shop and sync it automatically every one hour. because I don't have enough time to manage both.

is there any easy way to do this?
I don't know php coding as expert but I can edit some php codes if there is any clear guide.

Thanks